# errore with messageSignature sha256 in postman (base64 is notdefined.)

Tags: postman, sha256, postman-pre-request-script

I'm testing an api that i have to send in body those data acording to documentation:

```
studentId,
apiKey,
timeStamp (current iso time as a string),
messageSignature: apikey+studentId+timeStamp encrypted using sha256,
```

i wrote a script to generate message signature  using sha256 in Pre-request Script.
Pre-request Script:

```js
    var dateIso = new Date().toISOString();
    pm.globals.set("isoDateTostring", dateIso);
    console.log('timestamp var is:', pm.globals.get("isoDateTostring"));
    
    let msg = "apiKeyvalue" + "studentId" + pm.globals.get("isoDateTostring");+ JSON.stringify(msg)
    
    const hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, "secretKey");
    hmac.update(msg);
    const messageSignature = hmac.finalize().toString();
```

*Details (like screenshots)*:
in body i wrote:

```
{
"studentId":"********",
"apiKey":"************",
"timeStamp":{{$isoDateTostring}},
"messageSignature": {{$messageSignature}}
}
```

when i send the request i get base64 is notdefined.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code would be like:

**In Tab Body:**

`{{$isoDateTostring}}` --> `"{{isoDateTostring}}"`

`{{$messageSignature}}` --> `"{{messageSignature}}"`

```json
{
    "studentId": "123",
    "apiKey": "123abc",
    "timeStamp": "{{isoDateTostring}}",
    "messageSignature": "{{messageSignature}}"
}
```

**In tab Pre-request:** I fake `studentId` and `apiKey`

```js
const dateIso = new Date().toISOString();
pm.globals.set("isoDateTostring", dateIso);

const studentId = "123";
const apiKeyvalue = "123abc"
let msg = apiKeyvalue + studentId + pm.globals.get("isoDateTostring");

const messageSignature = CryptoJS.SHA256(msg).toString();
pm.globals.set("messageSignature", messageSignature);
```

**Result:**

```json
{
    "studentId": "123",
    "apiKey": "123abc",
    "timeStamp": "2021-10-26T13:20:09.068Z",
    "messageSignature": "783e65ff1cfb2374fb5f84daa35c01d18b8a1898b3a1837e84934e91a3c0720d"
}
```

Comment: I corret it as you told me, but i'm still get this error:{"status": 400,"error": {"expose": true,"statusCode": 400,"status": 400,"body": "{\r\n   \"studentId\":\"stId\",\r\n    \"apiKey\":\"12345A\",\r\n    \"timeStamp \":2021-10-26T13:42:14.944Z,\r\n    \"messageSignature\": 0az039883D\r\n}",
"type": "entity.parse.failed"},"message": "Unexpected number in JSON at position 96",
"stack": "SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 96\n

Comment: at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)\n    at parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)\n    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18\n    at invokeCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)\n    at done (/usr/src/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/usr/src/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)"}

Comment: No, you're not following my suggestion. Please douple check the request body. `2021-10-26T13:42:14.944Z`--> `"2021-10-26T13:42:14.944Z"`, `0az039883D` -> `"0az039883D"`

Comment: This is my body request (fake studentId and apiKey) :
{
    "studentId": "123",
    "apiKey": "123abc",
    "timeStamp ": {{isoDateTostring}},
    "messageSignature": {{messageSignature}}
}

Comment: Can you simply copy my code? It takes too nuch time for very simple thing. You are missing double quote for string for date and message.

Comment: Thks, it's ok for this part, but now it sent error 407Proxy Authentication Required (    "message": "Invalid Message Signature")

Comment: i added image of the error in the first question, i think maybe it's a problem with message signature

Comment: I just use https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#hashing to hash, no secret here. So the problem might be server using different hash algo. Please check with dev and it's helpful if you have correct sample.

Comment: i think so, the server use different algo, your code and your effort were very helpful.

Comment: i checked with developer, he uses this code to hash:   const crypto = require('crypto');
//hash is the message signature
const hash = crypto
.createHmac('sha256', secretKey)
.update(concatenatedData)
.digest('hex');   i'm tried with this code on posteman var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("msg", "secret_key");
var hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, "secret_key");
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(msg, "secret_key");
hmac.update(msg);
var hash = hmac.finalize(); but it sent array

Comment: @albertyaz Can you update to your question. thanks

Comment: it's ok, the script i wrote in question past to dev requirement ;)

Comment: @albertyaz cool, good to here that.